# Linux SED script find the 1st line that match pattern and delete it

Tags: linux, full-text-search, sed

I want to create a sed command to find in a file the 1st line that matchs a pattern and the delete all that line or replace it all with some other text. I dont want to match all the line because the rule is to match part of it.

how can i do it with sed?

for instance:

```
myline 1 is pretty
line 2 is ugly
myline 111 is nice
```

I want to delete the first line that contains "1 is"

UPDATE: My line may have characters like "/" and "<"

Regards
Fak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use `awk` for more complicated tasks, it's a bit more powerful than `sed`, having proper looping and selection constructs (expanded for readability, you can compress it back to one line if you wish):

```
pax$ echo '
xyz
myline 1 is pretty
line 2 is ugly
myline 111 is nice'  | awk '
     /1 is/ {if (f) {print} else {f = 1}}
    !/1 is/ {print}'

xyz
line 2 is ugly
myline 111 is nice
```

For any line *not* matching the pattern (`!/1 is/`), it just prints it.

For lines that *do* match the pattern, it prints them all if the flag `f` is set (it's initially not set). When the flags not set and it encounters a matching line, it sets the flag and doesn't print it. This basically deletes the first matching line as desired.

If you want to modify the first matching line rather than deleting it, you just insert code alongside the `f = 1` to do that, something like:

```
pax$ echo '
xyz
myline 1 is pretty
line 2 is ugly
myline 111 is nice'  | awk '
     /1 is/ {if (f) {print} else {f = 1;print "URK!!!"}}
    !/1 is/ {print}'

xyz
URK!!!
line 2 is ugly
myline 111 is nice
```

---

To use a shell variable in `awk`, you can use the `-v` option to pass it in as a real `awk` variable:

```
pax$ export xyzvar=URK ; echo '
xyz
myline 1 is pretty
line 2 is ugly
myline 111 is nice'  | awk -vmyvar=$xyzvar '
     /1 is/ {if (f) {print} else {f = 1;print myvar}}
    !/1 is/ {print}'

xyz
URK
line 2 is ugly
myline 111 is nice
```

Comment: great it works, but can you explain how to do that same command using a source text file instead of echoing and pipping to awk?

update: i get it... awk 'instruction' filename

Comment: can you explain instead of replaceing the line with URK!! i can use a bash variable to replace that text? i can't use print $myvar inside the awk... :(

Comment: @Fakada, you use `-v` to pass in shell variables as `awk` variables - see the update.

Comment: Not sure why OP selected this as the solution. Nor why it was even offered. The request was for `sed`, not `awk`. The solution below for `sed` is far simpler and gets the desired result much more succinctly. @paxdiablo mentions using `awk` to work on more complicated tasks. Deleting the first occurrence of a regex is hardly complex and, in fact, in this case using `awk` makes it so.

Comment: @theillien, it was _offered_ because awk is as ubiquitous as sed and because sometimes the user doesn't always _know_ which tools are available or best suited. This is confirmed by the fact that the OP accepted it since they wouldn't have done that if it didn't solve the problem. Now it may be that another answer is better and I've called in the past for a extra view based solely on votes (where the accepted answer isn't necessarily on top) since it seems logical that the person asking the question doesn't always have the required knowledge to choose the best answer. But it was rejected.

Comment: So what I tend to do is skip the accepted answer to questions I'm looking into and just go straight to the highest-voted, in the belief that the SO swarm knows better. That _may_ be the accepted answer or it may not.

Answer (score 7):

From the `sed` [FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.11):

```
sed '0,/RE/{//d;}' file        # delete only the first match
sed '0,/RE/s//to_that/' file   # change only the first match
```

If you are not using GNU `sed`, then check out the alternatives in the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it without sed. Bash script:

```shell
LINE=$(grep -n "$EXPR" "$FILE" |head -1 |cut -f1 -d:)
head -$(expr $LINE - 1 ) $FILE
tail +$(expr $LINE + 1 ) $FILE
```

Just declare `$EXPR` and `$FILE`.